# Type cannot be constructed: String after JSON to APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, json, apexrest

Json to Apex conversion is done and while saving the class in Salesforce ORG throws error.Type cannot be constructed: String

```
{
"accounts" : {
    "data" : [{
            "access_token" : "EAACEdEostrtre0cBAN0i40rLaxz1E79BH5QngiwStR7DoaQsX7ZAFJ1QLm66fo07W76WYGqU4X1GjC8uqqcGawOA6MBms5gZAfo0VQA4kch3ltoIPd86zBK1ecLzznS5hdTizYZBYqpsIse9jVqA0PZCIIeVR6WAA46sTjJZBW8ZBnqgZDZD",
            "category" : "Organization",
            "name" : "Busyday",
            "id" : "1616378787867178658991",
            "perms" : [
                "ADMINISTER",
                "EDIT_PROFILE",
                "CREATE_CONTENT",
                "MODERATE_CONTENT",
                "CREATE_ADS",
                "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "paging" : {
        "cursors" : {
            "before" : "MTYxNjrtrtM2NzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD",
            "after" : "MTYxNjMretrt2NzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD"
        }
    }
},
"id" : "1150203232221712395"
}

public class facebookpages {
public static void consumeObject(JSONParser parser) {
    Integer depth = 0;
    do {
        JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if (curr == JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
            curr == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
            depth++;
        } else if (curr == JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
            curr == JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            depth--;
        }
    } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
}

public Accounts accounts {get;set;} 
public String id {get;set;} 

public facebookpages(JSONParser parser) {
    while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String text = parser.getText();
            if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                if (text == 'accounts') {
                    accounts = new Accounts(parser);
                } else if (text == 'id') {
                    id = parser.getText();
                } else {
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Root consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                    consumeObject(parser);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Paging {
    public Cursors cursors {get;set;} 

    public Paging(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'cursors') {
                        cursors = new Cursors(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Paging consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Cursors {
    public String before {get;set;} 
    public String after {get;set;} 

    public Cursors(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'before') {
                        before = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'after') {
                        after = parser.getText();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Cursors consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Data {
    public String access_token {get;set;} 
    public String category {get;set;} 
    public String name {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public List<String> perms {get;set;} 

    public Data(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'access_token') {
                        access_token = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'category') {
                        category = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'name') {
                        name = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'id') {
                        id = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'perms') {
                        perms = new List<String>();
                        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            perms.add(new String(parser)); // Throws ERROR
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Data consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Accounts {
    public List<Data> data {get;set;} 
    public Paging paging {get;set;} 

    public Accounts(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'data') {
                        data = new List<Data>();
                        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            data.add(new Data(parser));
                        }
                    } else if (text == 'paging') {
                        paging = new Paging(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Accounts consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public static facebookpages parse(String json) {
    return new facebookpages(System.JSON.createParser(json));
}
}
```

https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can't construct a string, with or without parameters. It has no constructors defined. The error tells you exactly what's going wrong. You can never do:

```
String someText = new String(...);
```

As for what to do instead, you should be able to use `parser.getText()` like you do everywhere else. Honestly you should drop the parser altogether and just use serialization. Why reinvent the wheel?

```
public static FacebookPages parse(String payload) {
    return JSON.deserialize(payload, FacebookPages.class);
}
```